# The Pictures of my website aren't displayed online, only in local mode

Tags: reactjs, json, firebase-hosting

I am developing a photo album application in Reactjs.

The application works well locally, photos appear on the screen. I hosted my website on Google Firebase. The problem is that once hosted the photos no longer appear. The photos path is in a Json file.

I think the problem is with the path (localhost:3000) which is bad, but I don't know how to solve it.

Here is the website address: you will see that no photos appear: https://picturescope-596d0.web.app/

Here is the Github address of my project. : https://github.com/CaptainBeatty/picturescope

I would to display my picture as the local mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your image path is formatted wrong. It is written as

```
background-image: url("../../public/image-3.jpg");
```

This is not a valid url for a hosted application. This url should be a proper url path. If the images are static, you can check out [webpack](https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-images/) to bundle images into your react app, and use them in your components. An other option for when your images are dynamic, or can update over time; is to host the files on the server-side and then you can use a relative path (like "/public/image-3.jpg" depending on how you set up the the server).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm considering linking my application to a server. But I want to know how without. How to do in my case. I tries to change the url of my pictures but it didn't work.

Comment: @CaptainBeatty then you have two options in my eyes. Either host the images somewhere else on some image hosting platform, or use webpack to add the images to the application bundle. when going for hosting your images somewhere else, you change the localhost urls to urls of the image hosting platform. If you go for webpack, you will be able to import images like "import image from '../../image.jpg'". Then you can use the image variable as the variable holding your image url. But that won't work inside of a json file, so you would have to move the json content to a javascript file.